# MEAN Stack user authentication with passport-local and $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm using passport-local to log users into my application. we login via the below function which is called in my angularJS controller.

```
$http.post('/login', $scope.user).then(function (response){
    if(response.data.success){
        //If successful I console.log the user data and redirect them to the main page.
        console.log(response.data.user);
        $location.path(response.data.redirectTo);
    } else {
        // Handle the error messages passed back by my express routing.
    }
});
```

This is working as expected, if I login with the correct details then it will console.log the user and then redirect me to the new page.

My question is how do I now make it so all of my other pages will make sure that the user has logged in? What should I be using with the user data that I am receiving? 
The pages I am talking about use the below $routeProvider routing:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    // Something to make sure the user is logged in
  });

}])
```

All of the tutorials I have read are requiring me to handle this via the express routing but that just causes a redirect loop since `/login` doesn't pass the `isAuthenticated` routing middleware.

```
app.get('*', isAuthenticated, function(req,res){
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});

function isAuthenticated(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Any help on how to move forward from here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angularJs app needs to detect when a login is required. For this you need to write an interceptor for all responses you get from your express app and if a login is required, show the login page. In the best world,  your express app should not be redirecting to /login, you should leave the routing to your angularJs app; it shall just send json resources or something such as an 401 Status Code Response to indicate that the request is unauthorized.

Upon reception of the unauthorized headers, your angularJs interceptor will see that a login is required and show the login page:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {

    //configure $http to show a login dialog whenever a 401 unauthorized response arrives
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(
            function($rootScope, $q, $location) {

                return function(promise) {
                    return promise.then(
                            //success -> don't intercept            
                            function(response) {
                                return response;
                            },
                            //error -> if 401 save the request and broadcast an event
                                    function(response) {
                                if (response.status === 403 || response.status === 401) {
                                            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                                                    req = {
                                                        path: $location.path(),
                                                        config: response.config,
                                                        deferred: deferred
                                                    };
                                            $rootScope.requests401.push(req);
                                            $rootScope.$broadcast('event:loginRequired');
                                            return deferred.promise;
                                        }
                                        return $q.reject(response);
                                    }
                            );
                        };
            });
         });            
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location, base64) {


/**
 * Holds all the requests which failed due to 401 response.
 */
$rootScope.requests401 = [];

$rootScope.$on('event:loginRequired', function() {
    $location.path('/login');
});

/**
 * On 'event:loginConfirmed', resend all the 401 requests.
 */
$rootScope.$on('event:loginConfirmed', function(){

    var i, requests = $rootScope.requests401,
            retry = function(req) {
                $http(req.config).then(function(response) {
                    req.deferred.resolve(response);
                });
            };

        });
});
```

In this setting, your LoginCtrl needs to also emit the loginConfirmed event. Once you have the user from the login, you can store the details in the root scope for later access for instance.